# C++ base class function call from last derived in diamond design

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, diamond-problem

I'm learning C++ and after having read and tested a lot about multiple inheritance, virtual inheritance/methods and diamond design I still have some problems to understand it till the end.

I'm in the diamond design pattern, where class B e C inherit `virtual public A` and D inherits `public B, public C`:

```
    A
  /   \
 B     C
  \   /
    D
```

All classes implement a private variable `std::string _message` that I initialize with the following string.

```
 "class-name instance"
```

Only `Class A` implements a `virtual public display(void) const` method too.

```
void     display(void) const{
     std::cout << this->_message << std::endl;
}
```

The main is:

```
D foo;
foo.display();
```

The output is:

```
A instance
```

However when I "inspect" the element debugging step by step with Xcode I see that inside the D instance I can correctly find a B, a C and A object (just one shared by B and C) with all the different `_message` correctly assigned.

What I'm doing wrong? Need I override the `display()` method in D class? But if so, which is the real point of multiple inheritance if I have to re-implements the same method in a derived class?

Comment: I've heard "diamond problem", "dreaded diamond" and "diamond of death". I don't think I've seen anyone call it "diamond design pattern" before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to not be related to the diamond pattern, but is generally about the inheritance model in C++. Most things in C++ are statically bound, so at compile time the compiler fixes what method or member of a certain name is used:

If you access a member of the implicit `this` object or using a pointer or reference to an object, you will end up accessing a member of the class the pointer or reference has at compile time, no matter whether at runtime there is a derived-class object that has members of the same name. That's why they say you can not *override* but just *shadow* members in base classes when you define an equal named member in the derived class.

The same thing is true for non-virtual functions.

The *only* thing that behaves different is virtual functions. These functions can be overwritten in derived classes, and code that gets handed a pointer-to-base-class can virtual functions of the base class and end up executing implementations given in the derived class.

So the point of virtual functions is not to have the compiler reinterpret a certain function in the context of derived classes (as you seem to understand it), but to make it possible to replace a function in the base class by a *different* function in the derived class.

To go back to your motivation: If you want a `display` function that prints a message that depends on the actual object type, the thing that is fixed is the printig, which doesn't need to be virtual. But you need a virtual function to obtain the object type. Like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

class A {
public:
    void display() { std::cout << get_message() << '\n'; }
    virtual const char * get_message() { return "A instance"; }
};

class B : virtual public A {
public:
    virtual const char * get_message() { return "B instance"; }
};

class C : virtual public A {
public:
    virtual const char * get_message() { return "C instance"; }
};

class D : public B, public C {
public:
    // virtual const char * get_message() { return B::get_message(); }
    // virtual const char * get_message() { return C::get_message(); }
    // virtual const char * get_message() { return "D instance"; }
};

int main(void)
{
    D foo;
    foo.display();
    A* a_ptr = &foo;
    a_ptr->display();
    return 0;
}
```

The example as given will not compile (now this is due to the diamond pattern), because the compiler can not decide, what overrider of `A::get_message()`, either `B::get_message()` or `C::get_message()` should be picked in D objects, you need to make one of the comments in D real code to declare the one-and-only `get_message` for D, in which can re-use the existing functions.

Comment: Thank you! "So the point of virtual functions is not to have the compiler reinterpret a certain function in the context of derived classes (as you seem to understand it)  but to make it possible to replace a function in the base class by a different function in the derived class." This sentence clarified everything to me. I can obtain what I wanted also by implementing display() as a normal member function that calls a getter (declared virtaul in class A and overridden in class D". So in the main:  D foo; foo.dispaly() will output "D instance".